# How to connect DB2 to Cognos Dynamic Dashboard Embedded on IBM Cloud

Tags: db2, ibm-cloud, cognos, db2-woc

I have an IBM Cloud account with a DB2 (SMP Small), a Cognos Dynamic Dashboard Embedded services provisioned and a .php app bpund to the DB2 instance.

I managed to find some simple tutorials on how to create a session and a framework for the API using this:
https://dde-us-south.analytics.ibm.com/daas/DashboardAPI.html

but I have 2 problems right up front. A) when I go to "Add source" the API has a "test source" but when I pull anything form that source into my dashboard that I am creating I am getting a "query service internal error has occured, please see the log for details" .... and B) what I really want to do is get this dashboard to connect to my DB2 ... and pull data from there for vizualizations?

Comment: Could you add the JSON for the Db2 data source?

Comment: I am using DDE with Db2, but only indirectly - implementing multi-tenant access. Code: https://github.com/data-henrik/github-traffic-stats  Tutorial: https://console.bluemix.net/docs/tutorials/serverless-github-traffic-analytics.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For accessing JDBC sources, especially the table definition, you can [follow what is documented](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/cognos-dashboard-embedded/working_with_datasources.html#working-with-data-sources). For accessing Db2 (on-prem or cloud) sources, use something similar to what is below. Adapt to your settings.

```
{
    "xsd": "https://ibm.com/daas/module/1.0/module.xsd",
    "source": {
        "id": "StringID",
        "jdbc": {
            "jdbcUrl": "jdbcUrl: `jdbc:db2://DATABASE-HOST:50000/YOURDB`",
            "driverClassName": "com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver",
            "schema": "DEFAULTSCHEMA"
        },
        "user": "user_name",
        "password": "password"
    },
```

I have written an app that uses Db2 data, but wraps it into CSV format because of additional filters. [You can access the code in the GitHub repository here](https://github.com/IBM-Cloud/github-traffic-stats). There is a table definition in this [JSON file for the dashboard](https://github.com/IBM-Cloud/github-traffic-stats/blob/master/backend/dashboard.json). The overall scenario is described in this [IBM Cloud solution tutorial](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/tutorials/serverless-github-traffic-analytics.html).

Comment: Keep in mind that the connection JSON *is visible* to end users, so it is imperative that your app encrypts that portion of the spec before sending it back to the browser, from where the Cognos Dashboard Embedded javascript will process it.

See
https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/services/cognos-dashboard-embedded?topic=cognos-dashboard-embedded-encryptingdatasourceinformation

Comment: Hey @data_henrik,
I'm using private(hosted on internal n/w) DB2 database and when i'm performing addsource action as you mentioned above then i'm unable to load the data.
Error ---
"https://dde-us-south.analytics.ibm.com/daas/v1/data?moduleUrl=%2Fda......."  gets failed siting the reason , the above API is forbidden.

My question is - even though i'm providing credentials as above how it fails to load data and says  its forbidden.
Could you please advise how to overcome this.

Note- above code works for public database (hosted with public IP) .

Comment: @Vishu, I answered in your other SO question. You need to create a network connection first.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote something exactly like that, Cognos Dashboard Embedded reading data from DB2 in the IBM Cloud:
https://github.com/nastacio/cognos-de

Note that the code also use the encryption feature, so that the end-user cannot see the dashboard specification, from where they could gather DB2 URL and credentials.